# A library is internally compiling another version of a library that I need externally?

Tags: android, gradle, jar, aar, libs

There's a library that I need to integrate in my project:

> adobeMobileLibrary-4.14.0.jar

But when I try to run it gives me this error:

[image]

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/adobe/mobile/AbstractDatabaseBacking$CorruptedDatabaseException.class

So I found that a compiled .aar library is internally compiling the same adobeMobileLibrary but in another version.

[image]

What would be the best way to solve this type of problem?

Comment: What is `modelCommonsApi-release`?

Comment: It's an internal library of my company

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46569979/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-found-version/46570131#46570131

Comment: Then ask the developers of the internal library to use transitive dependencies, rather than baking a copy of that library in theirs.

Comment: I'm on that way. But, what if, in some cases, I do not have contact with the provider of a library?